# What does `squares xs = [x*x|x<-xs]` means in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

What does `squares xs = [x*x|x<-xs]` means.

Like i understand `[x*x|x<-[1,2,3]]`.

To be precise, Where does the `s` come from in `xs`?

Comment: same as `squares argument = [x*x|x<-argument]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xs` is a list argument passed to the `squares` function. Typically an `s` is used after a variable name in haskell to denote a list (IE, to pluralize the name to denote multiple values in the argument).

Answer (score 1):

According to Philip Walder the list is a strange animal which has a head and a tail only. And the tail consists of a head and a tail and so on till it is null.

for example for the function:

```
squareRec :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
squareRec [] = []
squareRec (x:xs) = x*x : squareRec xs
```

The solution works like:

```
squareRec[1,2,3]
= squareRec(1 : (2 : (3 : [])))
= 1*1 : squareRec(2 : (3 : []))
= 1*1 : (2*2 : squareRec(3 : []))
= 1*1 : (2*2 : (3*3 : squareRec []))
= 1*1 : (2*2 : (3*3 : []))
= 1 : (4 : (9 : []))
```

here the head is `x` (an element) and the tail is the rest of the list (which is a list). The returned list is passed in the `squareRec` function, while we get an empty list which is define as `squareRec [] = []`

And we know that `1:(4:(9:[])) = [1,4,9]`

Comment: If this problem as solved, consider marking your answer as accepted (this is also known as *self-accepting*). Refer to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/220538) post for more details.

Answer (score 0):

`xs` is just a variable (argument passed to `squares`). In your second example you just substituted `xs` with `[1,2,3]`.

Comment: Perhaps it becomes obvious if we rewrite the function to read `squares someList = [x*x | x <- someList]`